# Usage of "advancement" for software improvement - correct?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, synonyms

a colleague wrote a new suggestion for a more sophisticated business logic for one of our software processes. She used a title like this "xy advancement for process xy". That sounds strange to me: I would rather use "improvement" or perhaps "enhancement". But English is not my native language. My question: Is this usage correct? If yes, is there a slightly different meaning?

Comment: It depends on the actual 'xy's. E.g. signal *enhancement* for phone calls, UI *improvement* for process control, media *advancement* for process 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Software people are not generally known for their skill at English. (I am not being snippy. I wrote software in the distant past. But most people writing software do not view writing good prose as demanding an art as writing good code and so have not devoted time or thought to writing clear, concise, and exact prose.)

"Advancement" has the connotation of progress through a defined hierarchy.

"Her advancement to Vice President for Sales was rapid."

"Advance" can be used as a synonym for "improvement." If what is being described is materially more than incremental, "advance" may imply that better than mere "improvement."

Comment: Ok. Thanks for clarification and examples.

Although I agree that many (not all) developers are not good with writing text in this case its a business user who wrote the request (non-native speaker). I guess she googled the translation for German "Verbesserung" and then you will get all three words as a result: improvement, enhancement and advancement.

Comment: In defense of software developers, prose should not really be considered in the field. The naming conventions are much closer related to a _scientific_ context, where words have strict definitions and are not open to interpretation. It's not that software developers "have not devoted time or thought to writing clear, concise, and exact prose", it's that **they should not try to be prosaic** in the first place. Arguments can be made for allowing it in documentation, but even there I would prefer accuracy over aesthetics, because the documentation needs to be in line with the code itself.

Comment: @ Flater As I said, I used to write software so I agree that documentation needs to be written to tight, technical standards. But for close to 20 years, my sins required that I supervise a large IT department as well as numerous departments that relied on that IT department. People in that IT department had to communicate with other people and were generally atrocious at doing so. And, for many, their attitude was indeed that "they should not try to be competent at writing prose." By the way, "prosaic" does not mean "competent at writing prose in a natural language."